# How to change the position of axis values in nomogram, rms package?

Tags: r, regression

How do I change the axis values of the rms r package! from horizontal to vertical like style. Below is a code extracted from the rms package! The axis values are in horizontal style. I want to change it to the vertical style and I can seem to figure it out, I appreciate any help! Thanks

```
n <- 1000    # define sample size
set.seed(17) # so can reproduce the results
d <- data.frame(age = rnorm(n, 50, 10),
                blood.pressure = rnorm(n, 120, 15),
                cholesterol = rnorm(n, 200, 25),
                sex = factor(sample(c('female','male'), n,TRUE)))

# Specify population model for log odds that Y=1
# Simulate binary y to have Prob(y=1) = 1/[1+exp(-L)]
d <- upData(d,
  L = .4*(sex=='male') + .045*(age-50) +
       (log(cholesterol - 10)-5.2)*(-2*(sex=='female') + 2*(sex=='male')),
  y = ifelse(runif(n) < plogis(L), 1, 0))

ddist <- datadist(d); options(datadist='ddist')


f <- lrm(y ~ lsp(age,50) + sex * rcs(cholesterol, 4) + blood.pressure,
         data=d)
nom <- nomogram(f, fun=function(x)1/(1+exp(-x)),  # or fun=plogis
    fun.at=c(.001,.01,.05,seq(.1,.9,by=.1),.95,.99,.999),
    funlabel="Risk of Death")
#Instead of fun.at, could have specified fun.lp.at=logit of
#sequence above - faster and slightly more accurate
plot(nom, xfrac=.45)
print(nom)
nom <- nomogram(f, age=seq(10,90,by=10))
plot(nom, xfrac=.45)
g <- lrm(y ~ sex + rcs(age, 3) * rcs(cholesterol, 3), data=d)
nom <- nomogram(g, interact=list(age=c(20,40,60)), 
                conf.int=c(.7,.9,.95))
plot(nom, col.conf=c(1,.5,.2), naxes=7)

w <- upData(d,
            cens = 15 * runif(n),
            h = .02 * exp(.04 * (age - 50) + .8 * (sex == 'Female')),
            d.time = -log(runif(n)) / h,
            death = ifelse(d.time <= cens, 1, 0),
            d.time = pmin(d.time, cens))


f <- psm(Surv(d.time,death) ~ sex * age, data=w, dist='lognormal')
med  <- Quantile(f)
surv <- Survival(f)  # This would also work if f was from cph
plot(nomogram(f, fun=function(x) med(lp=x), funlabel="Median Survival Time"))
nom <- nomogram(f, fun=list(function(x) surv(3, x),
                            function(x) surv(6, x)),
            funlabel=c("3-Month Survival Probability", 
                       "6-month Survival Probability"))
plot(nom, xfrac=.7)

 [![This is the nomogram result][1]][1]
```

[image: How do I change the axis values of this image to the one shown below]

[image: To this one here!]

[image: My current problem]

Comment: Just did @JohanLarsson

Comment: I had a look through the function `rms:::plot.nomogram` and I don't think there is an easy way to accomplish this. I am guessing that you at a minimum would have to adjust all the calls to `rms:::axisf` and then perhaps rotate the entire plot using something from `library(gridBase)`.

Comment: still a beginner and i am getting some errors when i am setting up the rms:::axisf, will keep trying I appreciate if you could share the code in case of success, @Johan Larsson

Comment: Unless you are going to generate a lot of figures, may I suggest that you just bite the bullet and edit the figure in an image editor? It is probably going to be quicker.

Comment: I will update my question to late you see the problem, the values are too compressed and some are not visible @Johan Larsson

Comment: @Johan Larsson, can you check the last image

Comment: Try using `label.every` and `xfrac` arguments to get what you want.

Comment: Gonna try using label.every because xfrac didn't work @Johan Larsson

Comment: getting this error :Error in nomogram(flrm, fun = plogis, fun.at = c(0.01, 0.05, seq(0.1,  : 
  factor name(s) not in the design: label.every

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138196/discussion-between-johan-larsson-and-drexxx).

Comment: Thanks mate! will do that